# I would like to set arrays indirectly in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file where every 4 lines there is a block of information. I have set up 4 arrays named @linearray1, @linearray2, @linearray3, @linearray4.

I also have a counter than gets incremented for every four lines called $lineno.

I would like to set the four arrays and then parse them out appropriately.

But rather than set them directly four times I would like to do it in one line and then just check $lineno at 5 to do the rest.

So rather than writing out :
   @linearray1=split(",",$_)

I want to do something like:
   @linearray.$lineno=split(",",$_);

Comment: You really don't want to do that. What you want is a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't generate variable names.](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Instead, use

```
@{ $lines[$lineno] } = split /,/;
```

Or more directly:

```
$lines[$lineno] = [ split /,/ ];
```

Or even

```
push @lines, [ split /,/ ];
```

You can access elements using

```
for my $lineno (0..$#lines) {
   say join ', ', @{ $lines[$lineno] };
}
```

or

```
for my $line (@lines) {
   say join ', ', @$line;
}
```

Remember to always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable as the name of a variable (or part of that name) in Perl. The syntax you're trying to find is:

```
@{'linearray'.$lineno} = split(',', $_);
```

Since `split` will default to `$_` in the absense of a second arg, and for the sake of a complete answer, you can do:

```
foreach $lineno (1..4) @{'linearray'.$lineno} = split ',';
```

Don't get confused by the `{}` in that syntax, there's no hash dereference going on, but when you have a sigil followed immediately by an open brace, the outcome of the expression in the braces is used as the name of the variable.

Is there a reason you can't use a two-dimensional array, like `@{$linearray[$lineno]}`? That's considered to be cleaner, and is almost certainly a little faster.

Comment: Would have to be `@{$linearray[$lineno]}`, but yeah, a two-dimensional array is the sane way to go.

Comment: Yeah it's been a while and I forgot that perl didn't have native n-dimensional arrays. What he said.

Comment: `@{$linearray[$lineno]}` can also be written `$linearray->[$lineno]`, which IMHO looks much better.

Comment: No, mirod, that's completely different. `$linearray->[$lineno]` would be if `$linearray` itself was an arrayref. The equivalent to that would be `$$linearray[$lineno]` I think. Or maybe `${$linearray}[$lineno]`, which is pretty hairy. In this case I'm suggesting that he use an array of arrays, where either `linearray` is an array, you access the subarrays with `@{$linearray[$line]}`, and you access the elements with `$linearray[$line]->[$elem]`, or `linearray` is an arrayref, you access the subarrays with `@{$linearray->[$line]}`, and you access the elements with `$linearray->[$line]->[$elem]`

Comment: @Dan I cannot leave a question that primarily recommends symbolic references undownvoted.

Comment: But that's what the questions was about!

Comment: @Dan Oops! Sorry. The heat got to me.

Comment: @Dan Not really. OP intuitively assumed there might be “something like” symrefs. This does not mean OP really wants to use them. It is much more likely he didn’t know about AoAs and real references. You might want to read about [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the question asks about a *solution* which in reality is suboptimal.

Comment: Downvoted. Recommending symbolic references for this is a terrible idea.